# int to string, char*  itoa

Tags: c++, string, char, int

trying to get ‘sval’ to contain the string “$1” – “$500” for array indexes 0-499.  in the following code, however itoa is giving me strange strings in the code below:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;


    typedef struct data_t {
        int ival;
        char *sval;
    } data_t;

    void f1(data_t **d);
    int main()
    {
    data_t *d;

        d=static_cast<data_t*>(malloc(500));  //is this even needed?
        d = new data_t[500];
        f1(&d);
    }

    /* code for function f1 to fill in array begins */
    void f1(data_t **d)
    {
        int i;
        char str[5];
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
        {
            (*d)[i].ival=i+1;
            itoa (i,str,10);
            (*d)[i].sval= str;
        }
    }
```

it also seems itoa has been depreciated, but that was what i got when i googled int to string

Comment: why? tell me, why `**d`????? Just so that you could do `(*d)[i]`? Really?!

Comment: You should not use both `malloc` and `new`. By the way, `malloc` should be called with `sizeof(data_t)*500` not `500`. But even better, you should never use `malloc` in C++, it was only inlcuded for compatibility with C.

Comment: @littleadv   not my code:  it's a test for an interview   it's there to throw me off

Comment: I recommend checking out [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: @Sun I would be insulted being asked such questions at an interview.

Comment: @Sun: So it's that kind of interview question when they show you a horrible, bug-ridden code, and you have to point out the mistakes?

Comment: yeah... i'm just a junior dev... only just got my associates...  and the stuff they throw at you... i'm thinking i need 4 more years of college before i can really understand this stuff

Comment: @Sun no, you need 4 more years of experience. That's not something they're going to teach you in college (and if it is - go to a different college, learning this at school is wasting your school time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `ltoa`, `cout` should be just fine. Why do you need to keep the number and its string representation in the array? when you do `cout << 10` you get "10" on the output, you don't need any conversions of your own

You, on the other hand, do `ltoa` without allocating any memory for the strings, which is not healthy as you have probably noticed. You use a local variable (the same, for all the 500 array members), which you try to access after you exit the function - a big no-no, its undefined behavior.

And:

```
    d=static_cast<data_t*>(malloc(500));  //is this even needed?
    d = new data_t[500];
```

No. Not only not needed - shouldn't be there at all! When in C++ - use `new` and `delete`, never `malloc`, that's a C function.

Comment: thanks for the info on malloc.

what would you suggest to do when trying to put "$1"-"$500"  into the sval?

Comment: I would suggest not doing it. If absolutely necessary - use `std::string`, not arrays of `char`s. If absolutely necessary to use the arrays - make sure to actually allocate some memory for them.

Comment: when you say to allocate memory for the arrays and the below code was bad (guessing global variable a nono?) , where do i allocate it?

additionally what would be the easiest way to get sval = $1-$500?

Comment: @Sun - I'm not sure I understand your question. You obviously would allocate it where you use it, and release it after you're done using it. You need to read a bit (or quite a lot actually) on dynamic memory handling in C++, its not a "comment level" topic.

Comment: i just need to get sval = $1-$500    :(