# int to char* and memory allocation

Tags: c++, string, char, int

this is prob pretty easy but if someone could explain the easiest way to get ‘sval’ to contain the string “$1” – “$500” for array indexes 0-499.  in the following code, however itoa is giving me strange strings in the code below:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;


    typedef struct data_t {
        int ival;
        char *sval;
    } data_t;

    void f1(data_t **d);
    int main()
    {
    data_t *d;

        d = new data_t[500];
        f1(&d);
    }

    /* code for function f1 to fill in array begins */
    void f1(data_t **d)
    {
        char str[5];
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
        {
            (*d)[i].ival = i+1;
            itoa (i+1,str,10);
            (*d)[i].sval = str;
        }
    }
```

it also seems itoa has been depreciated, but that was what i got when i googled int to string

or... trying it with stringstream i still get problems and i'm nowhere getting the '$' in the front, yet...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;


typedef struct data_t {
    int ival;
    char *sval;
} data_t;

void f1(data_t **d);
int main()
{
data_t *d;

    //d = static_cast<data_t*>(malloc(sizeof(data_t)*500));  //for legacy c
    d = new data_t[500];
    f1(&d);
}

/* code for function f1 to fill in array begins */
void f1(data_t **d)
{
    stringstream ss;
    char *str;

    for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        (*d)[i].ival=i+1;
        ss << i;
        str = ss.str();
        (*d)[i].sval= str;
    }
}
```

char * and string do not work well together... and again.. i'm still not sure how to get the "$" in front of the whole thing... ugh

oh... and if it helps.. this is the code given: and my requirements
The following program contains an array of structures of type data_t.  The declaration for the variable ‘d’ of type data_t is given.  Write logic into the main program to allocate memory for variable ‘d’ such it contains an array of 500 elements, each of type data_t.  Don’t bother with freeing the memory or testing the return value of malloc for NULL.  Then, write function ‘f1’ to fill in each of the 500 elements of the array such that the integer field ‘ival’ has the values 1-500 for array indexes 0-499 respectively, and the string field ‘sval’ contains the string “$1” – “$500” for array indexes 0-499 respectively.  The call for function ‘f1’ is given at the end of the main program.

```
typedef struct data_t {
    int ival;
    char *sval;
} data_t;
main()
{
data_t *d; /* declaration for an array of  data_t structures */
    /* allocate memory for a 500 element array of structures begins */
    /* allocate memory for a 500 element array of structures ends */
    f1(&d); /* function call to fill in array */
}
/* code for function f1 to fill in array begins */
f1(data_t **d)
{
}
/* code for function f1 to fill in array ends */
```

Comment: First of all, what you are using is c++ and not c.

Comment: I don't see you inserting a $ character in the array anywhere. I won't just appear by itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [int to string, char*  itoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083830/int-to-string-char-itoa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void f1(data_t **d)
{
    char str[5];
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        (*d)[i].ival = i+1;
        itoa (i+1,str,10);
        (*d)[i].sval = str;
    }
}
```

You're assigning each `sval` member to point to the same array (`str`).  That is, `(*d)[i].sval` will be pointing to the same memory location for all elements.  Worse, they're all pointing to a *local* array that will become garbage when `f1` returns.

If you want each array element's `sval` member to point to its own string, you must explicitly allocate memory yourself (and explicitly free it later).

```
void f1(data_t **d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        char *str = malloc(5);
        if (str == NULL) {
           abort(); // Or fail gracefully somehow.
        }

        (*d)[i].ival = i+1;
        itoa (i+1,str,10);
        (*d)[i].sval = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: THIS WORKS!!!  okay, so how can i add '$' to the front of that string?

something like  (*d)[i].sval = '$' + str;  doesn't work

Comment: Use `snprintf` instead of `itoa`.

Comment: `snprintf(str, 4, "$%i", i+1);`

Comment: okay this works, but the end values of sval = $1 then a bunch of ++=== and stuff

Comment: example output:     498  $498=zzzz   499  $499=zzzzz  500   $500=zzzz

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the struct definition, then the easiest thing to to is define it so that the bytes for `sval` are contained within the struct:

```
typedef struct data_t {
    int ival;
    char sval[5];
} data_t;
```

(Otherwise, you will need to use `malloc()` and `free()` as described in jamesdlin's answer.)

Then, to do the string conversion and insert the `$` character, you can use `snprintf()`. Like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
{
    (*d)[i].ival = i+1;
    snprintf((*d)[i].sval, 4, "$%i", i+1);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void f1(data_t **d)
{
    char str[5];
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        (*d)[i].ival = i+1;
        itoa (i+1,str,10);
        (*d)[i].sval= str; // <-- WRONG! str is allocated on the stack!
        // And you use the same char[] for the 500 data_t.sval
    }
}
```